# AzureDevops can't find csproj file when build Dockerfile

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a pipeline in AzureDevops, so I have the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

When I try to run my pipeline I got the following error:

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder651276881/WebApi/WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder651276881/WebApi/WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
```

I noted that AzureDevops build my Docker outsite the folder, with this command:

```
/usr/bin/docker build -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/WebApi/Dockerfile -t repository:9 /home/vsts/work/1/s/WebApi
```

I think I need enter in WebApi/ folder to execute the Build, because my Dockerfile try to copy the files.

Comment: just change your dockerfile paths?

Comment: Change where? Can you give example?

Comment: `COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]` >> `COPY ["WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]`

Comment: I think it don't work, because the docker command is executive outside the folder where is my app source

Comment: why do you think so, its executed here: `/home/vsts/work/1/s/WebApi` this looks like that folder exactly

Comment: Oh, it's true, sorry. I will try and return here

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41, your solution works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

changing dockerfile like so solves the problem:

```
COPY ["WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
```